# IE misreading UTF-8 in img src URL generated with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, xslt, utf-8

In my Windows desktop application, I generate an HTML report locally using XML and XSL. The report contains local images. Only Internet Explorer is supported for viewing the report.
If an image URL in this report contains UTF-8 characters, the image is not displayed in IE versions 9-11 (but Firefox is able to display it). In this case, the image URL in IE shows a sequence of latin characters in place of one UTF-8 character. For e.g., `á` (a with acute, represented as "%C3%A1" in UTF8) gets replaced with `Ã¡`. UTF-8 characters elsewhere in the report, including the `img` `alt` text, are displayed properly. Minimal XML and XSL for reproducing the issue:
**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="IE-issue.xsl"?>
<Image>C:/Temp/á_MyImage.jpg</Image>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Image">
        <html>
            <head>
                <h3>á Heading</h3>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:element name="img">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        file:///<xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                        file:///<xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="width">
                        400
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="height">
                        400
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The image path in this case is shown as "file:///C:/Temp/Ã¡_MyImage.jpg" in IE. IE screenshot:

[image: IE screenshot]

Note that in the DOM Explorer, the path is shown as " file:///C:/Temp/%C3%A1_MyImage.jpg". Also, the `alt` text displays the UTF-8 correctly.

On searching, found an encoding problem description similar to this:
http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-utf-8-latin1.html
It gives a couple of causes, but they are not applicable in my case.

Any ideas on how to resolve or work around this issue?

### Update 1 [17Nov2014]

HTML from IE and Firefox with @molbal and @MartinHonnen's suggestions:
**IE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <title>IE Issue</title>
  </head>
  <body abp="0">
    <h3 abp="1">á Heading</h3>
    <img width="400" height="400" src="file:///C:/Temp/%C3%A1_MyImage.jpg" alt="file:///C:/Temp/á_MyImage.jpg" abp="2">
  </body>
</html>
```

**Firefox:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
    <title>IE Issue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>á Heading</h3>
    <img width=" 400 " height=" 400 " src="file:///C:/Temp/á_MyImage.jpg" alt="file:///C:/Temp/á_MyImage.jpg"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have a few ideas that you could try out. Did you set the character encoging to UTF-8 on the XML file itself? IF that does not work you can also try adding a meta tag to your html head: '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'

Comment: The `src` attribute of an `img` element is a URL reference and therefore the XSLT processor is right in percent-encoding non-ASCII characters in such attribute values. Why do you put leading white space into the `src` attribute value? I would first try to avoid that by simply using `<img src="{.}" alt="{.}" width="400" height="400"/>`. Additionally I would make sure that IE is put into standards compliant rendering mode by using e.g. `<xsl:output method="html" version="4.01"
  indent="yes"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"/>`.

Comment: @molbal: I tried your suggestions, but no luck. I have updated my question to include HTML from IE and Firefox.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I tried your suggestions, but no luck. I have updated my question to include HTML from IE and Firefox.

Comment: I'm out of suggestions. Maybe one last very crude solution would bypass this issue: if you printed out the whole <img> tag and then that way the XSLT processor wouldn't try to encode the file path (as @MartinHonnen said)  Like this: http://pastebin.com/qUiHSeNC

Comment: @molbal Yes <xsl:text> did the trick! `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;img src=</xsl:text>"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">height="400" width="400"/&gt;</xsl:text>`. Can you please post your comment as answer, so i can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MartinHonnen said the XSLT processor encoding thr non-ASCII characters when binding the src value. This can be bypassed with printing the tag out yourself:

```
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;img src=</xsl:text>"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">height="400" width="400"/&gt;</xsl:text>
```